# Download images off Google with Python error?

Tags: python, image, download

New to Python, and I'm trying to automate downloading images off Google. I want to type in a keyword, and then have my program automatically go and download/save images from Google into a folder so it's available on my computer. Here's my code:

```
import json
import os
import time
import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError


def go(query, path):

 BASE_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?'\
         'v=1.0&q=' + query + '&start=%d'

 BASE_PATH = os.path.join(path, query)

 if not os.path.exists(BASE_PATH):
 os.makedirs(BASE_PATH)

start = 0 # Google's start query string parameter for pagination.
while start < 60: # Google will only return a max of 56 results.
r = requests.get(BASE_URL % start)
for image_info in json.loads(r.text)['responseData']['results']:
  url = image_info['unescapedUrl']
  try:
    image_r = requests.get(url)
  except ConnectionError, e:
    print 'could not download %s' % url
    continue

  # Remove file-system path characters from name.
  title = image_info['titleNoFormatting'].replace('/', '').replace('\\', '')

  file = open(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, '%s.jpg') % title, 'w')
  try:
    Image.open(StringIO(image_r.content)).save(file, 'JPEG')
  except IOError, e:
    # Throw away some gifs
    print 'could not save %s' % url
    continue
  finally:
    file.close()

print start
start += 4 # 4 images per page.


time.sleep(1.5)
```

## Example use

go('angry human face', 'myDirectory')

But I keep getting the error saying:

```
file = open(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, '%s.jpg') % title, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or 
filename: u'myDirectory\\landscape\\Nature - Landscapes - Views - Desktop Wallpapers |    MIRIADNA..jpg'
```

What do I do to fix this? Please help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename: u'... - Desktop Wallpapers |    MIRIADNA..jpg'
                                     ^ This is a problem
```

Windows does not allow the pipe character (`|`) in the filenames.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx:

> The following reserved characters:
>
> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)

In your case, the reserved characters are present in the titles of the pictures you are downloading and subsequently using for your filenames. You can strip these characters fairly easily, for example:

```
title = ''.join('%s' % lett for lett in [let for let in title if let not in '<>:"/\|?*'])
```

Comment: But there are no pipe characters?

Comment: But in the code itself, I didn't include any pipe characters. When I ran the program, it returned an error with that

Comment: @user3105664: Well, if `image_info['titleNoFormatting']` contains any of the characters that Windows doesn't allow in filenames, you have a problem.

Comment: The title of the image contains the reserved character, so you need to ensure that you strip any of those characters from your title before forming the filename.

Comment: @pseudocubic Can you edit in your suggestion? Thanks!